# When polynomial f(t+1/t) can be factored as g(t)·g(1/t)?

Tags: nt.number-theory, real-analysis, polynomials, algorithms

In venue of my old question [When polynomial f(x^2) can be factored as g(x)·g(-x)?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/123122) and [this recent answer](https://mathoverflow.net/q/261981) to a different question, I wonder:

How to characterize polynomials $f(x)$ with rational coefficients such that $f(t+t^{-1})=g(t)\cdot g(t^{-1})$, where $g(x)$ is also a polynomial with rational coefficients?

Is there a computationally efficient way to identify if a given polynomial $f(x)$ is such, without factoring $f(t+t^{-1})$ ?

Comment: I suspect the two questions may be related via the following substitution (Cayley transform): if $t = \frac{1+x}{1-x}$, then $\frac12 (t+t^{-1}) = \frac{1+x^2}{1-x^2}$.

Comment: Another observation derived from similar problems over $\mathbb{C}$ is that $f(\exp(i\theta)+\exp(-i\theta)) = g(\exp(i\theta))g(\exp(-i\theta)) = |g(\exp(i\theta)|^2 \geq 0$, so a necessary condition is that $f(x)\geq 0$ for each $x\in[-2,2]$.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni: Thanks for the nice observation. It reduces this new question to the old one. Please post your comments as an answer, and I'll accept it (to keep this question for the reference).

Comment: I think there is still some work to be done to get a full solution (for instance, to remove denominators and reduce to the polynomial case). It is quite late now in my time zone and I don't have the time to write a complete answer, but if you know how to put everything together please go on and write it yourself -- I will happily leave the imaginary internet points to you. :)